# Specified items will not be deleted when using ListView.Item.RemoveAt()

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listviewitem

I have tried to remove specific items from a listview using the `RemoveAt()` method. But When I remove it the first time some items will stay.

For example: see the image below

[image]

**Code:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++) 
        {
            if (listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text == "A1") 
            {
                listView1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("A1");
            lvi.SubItems.AddRange(new string[] {"desc" + i.ToString(), i.ToString()});
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("A2");
            lvi.SubItems.AddRange(new string[] { "desc" + i.ToString(), i.ToString() });
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.removeat.aspx) in the *Remarks* section.

> When you remove an item from the
>   collection, the indexes change for
>   subsequent items in the collection.
>   All information about the removed item
>   is deleted. You can use this method to
>   remove a specific item from the
>   collection by specifying the index of
>   the item to remove from the
>   collection. To specify the item to
>   remove instead of the index to the
>   item, use the Remove method. To remove
>   all items from the collection, use the
>   Clear method.

**Edit:** See Moot's answer. Link / reference above applies to his/her answer as well.

**Edit 2:**

Just back the counter up one if you find a match.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        if (listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text == "A1")
        {
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
            i--; // Back counter up one
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1, @TSS, if you change the `for` loop to start at the end and go to `0`, you can get rid of the `i--;`.

Answer (score 4):

When you delete the first A1, the list shrinks, and the element at 1 and 2 become your element at 0 and 1.  So, when your loop increments, it deletes the A1 at 1 (the third one) and skips the one which moved down to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var itemsToRemove = new List<ListViewItem>();

    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
    {
        if (item.SubItems[0].Text == "A1")
            itemsToRemove.Add(item);
    }

    foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
        listView1.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Good luck!